# Detect end of a meeting in MS Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Is there a way for a bot in MS Teams to detect the beginning/end of a meeting created in teams?

I’d like to show a message to all the attendees of the meeting after it is over.

The only way I can think of doing this is to periodically call the Microsoft graph API for calendars and check for new meetings.

However, this method can only detect scheduled calendar meetings and won’t work for direct calls or ad hoc meetings.

I also looked at bot events but there are no events for meetings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to support this currently. In fact we have a hard time detecting this ourselves - if someone forgets to leave the meeting, it stays open even if there's no activity on the line. We are still fine-tuning the timeout detection/logic - after all we can't use the scheduled time because meetings do run late.

And as far as I know, it's not on the roadmap either; you are the first person to have asked for it as far as I know, but I'll suggest it to the team - it's a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Recently came across this and, although it is a bit clumsy, it is a way to make sure no one stays in the meeting by accident.

In the Teams client, you can lookup the participants list and from there you can remove the participants from the meeting until there is no one left but you. This must be done for every individual participant.

Answer (score 0):

This has been added as `onTeamsMeetingEndEvent`

Just overriding this method is enough to handle this turn